# Azure insights to capture cpu utilization of a worker role

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I need to monitor cpu utilization of a worker role using Azure Insights, does anyone have a tutorial for this?

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: Did u check this one https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-cloudservices/ and this sample  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/Samples/AzureEmailService  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Azure Monitoring Services API as mentioned here https://convective.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/using-azure-monitoring-services-api-with-azure-cloud-services/